# SQL select as a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm selecting data from MySQL. My code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT oznacenie_odpadu FROM zdroj_dat ORDER by ID ASC";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
// fetch associative array
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['oznacenie_odpadu'].'"     >'.$row['oznacenie_odpadu'].'</option>';       
}
}
```

This part of code is in my code multiple times. I'm calling it 5times only string "oznacenie_odpadu" is changing. Therefore I made function:

```
function select($data) {
$sql = "SELECT rozmer FROM zdroj_dat ORDER by id ASC";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
// fetch associative array
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row[$data].'" >'.$row[$data].'</option>';       
    }
}
}
```

Calling it with select("somevalue");

Syntax is ok because I didn't change anything but when I load the page the data from database are not retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable scope issue. `$conn` is not available inside of your function. You need to pass it as a parameter so ic an be used inside of your function.

```
function select($conn, $data) {
    $sql = "SELECT rozmer FROM zdroj_dat ORDER by id ASC";

    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    // fetch associative array
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[$data].'" >'.$row[$data].'</option>';       
        }
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
select($conn, "somevalue");
```

Comment: Sir, you are right. Thanks.